# Convert DateTime to US and European

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a date in the format 2012-10-15 15:00:21.970

To European: 15/10/2012 15:00:21

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTime, 103) + N' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTime, 8)
-- 15/10/2012 15:00:21
```

To US: 10/15/2012 03:00:21 PM

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime, 101)
-- 10/15/2012
```

I can't figure out the time portion of the US conversion. I can probably do it with DATEPART, but this function is going to format times in a select statement, so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. Any ideas?

Resource: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Figured it out

```
DECLARE @DateTime datetime = '2012-10-15 15:00:21.970'
SELECT
CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTime, 101) + N' ' +
LEFT(N'0' + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTime, 109), 13), 8) + N' ' +
 CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,@DateTime) < 13
        THEN 'AM'
        ELSE 'PM'
        END
```

Comment: There is no "european" date format.

Comment: Then consider them date formats that I made up. Next to "US" and "European" is what I need the time to look like. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I would strongly urge you to [not use w3schools as a resource](http://www.w3fools.com). Please use the MSDN library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime, 101) + N' ' +CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(@DateTime AS time(0)), 109)
```

Comment: Edited to add seconds

Comment: I need a space before the AM/PM, but this is close enough I guess

Answer (score 2):

There are a [list of formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) supported by SQL Server, among them are various European formats. For example, here is the statement for German date format (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) AS [DD.MM.YYYY]
```