# Convert to dd/MM/yyyy from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

I have the following output that is stored in a string field:

**Query**

```
SELECT StringField5 FROM MyTable WHERE OrderID=1
```

**Output**

02/13/2018

I would like to use one of the ways SQL allow to convert/cast to get the following output:

13/02/2018.

I have tried the following code and a lot of them found on this website but none helped and always returned the first output described (02/13/2008):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25), StringField5, 103) FROM MyTable WHERE OrderID=1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2016.
What am I missing?

Comment: Add the <sql-server> tag. (The CONVERT function is SQL Server specific.)

Comment: Simply use `101' instead of '103' and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679009/convert-datetime-to-us-and-european

Comment: *Don't* store dates as strings. Use the proper type, eg `date`. Anything else just covers up the bug. Converting a *string* to another *string* is a very strange request too

Answer (score 2):

First convert your string date to a datetime, then convert that datetime back to the string output you expect:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25), CONVERT(datetime, '02/13/2018', 101), 103)
FROM MyTable
WHERE OrderID = 1;
```

### Demo

By the way, it is generally a bad idea to store your dates in the database as strings.  Always store your information as formal dates.

Comment: I get this error: `The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`.

Comment: @BeatriceToia Your data is the problem, not my query, which is working in the demo.  My guess is that you have some strings in there which can't be converted to dates.

Comment: I used `DATALENGTH` on that field and I get 20 as result and not 10 as it should be. Is there something I can do?

Comment: You need to figure out what data you actually have, and then proceed from there.  You might need an addtional step to filter off records with bad data, or maybe do an update to bring them to convertible dates.

Comment: @BeatriceToia why should it be *10*? If it's `nvarchar(10)` it will be 20 bytes long and still contain 10 characters. If the format is not what you thought though, you'll get conversion errors. Why assume it's a *US* string? `nvarchar` is still the *wrong* type to use to store dates though. SQL Server has a `date` type

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SELECT FORMAT(StringField5, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) FROM MyTable WHERE OrderID=1
```

See the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: Formating a *string* ? This will throw `Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - this is exactly what I got.

Comment: @BeatriceToia because formatting a string as a string is meaningless. Fix the field type. How can you be certain *all* strings use the US date format?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to convert from '02/13/2018' to '13/02/2018'

```
Select substring(StringField5,4,2)+'/'+ substring(StringField5,0,3)+'/'+ substring(StringField5,7,4) FROM MyTable WHERE OrderID=1
```